# PowerBI - Dynamic Column Name based on Parameter Selection

Tags: dynamic, parameters, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Goodmorning!

I am quite new to PowerBI, so please bear with me...

**In the report I am building, I want to be able to use one selector, to change both the rows which should be visible, as well as the columns which should be visible, including the column names.**

So far, I have managed to create a parameter with which the rows which need to be showed are selected (even with a simulated Hierarchy WOOOO!!!)
However, I struggle to create the columns.
I have been able to create a measure using SelectedValue to change the values that are shown.
**However, I cannot get my head around how to also change the name of the column in this case dynamically.**

Probably, I have not used the right terminology, so please ask if you need clarification.
All help is welcome!

Thanks! Margriet (Netherlands)

For the ones of you interested in creating a parameter with a simulated hierarchy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5G_xSJy5muo

I have tried selected value, adding another column to the parameter table, and the usual google research. Probably I do not use the right terms.

Comment: You cannot change the names of columns dynamically. Instead, think of it as showing/hiding the relevant columns. Tip: If a column returns null/blank for every row, then that column won't be shown - this is for Matrix visual (not Table).